# Python pandas explode (one to many relationship)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a the following dataframe with columns **name, preference, fruits**:

```
name   preference   fruits
adam    likes       apples
mike   dislikes     orange
```

If the dataframe above had a one to many relationship like column **name** would have have multiple relationship with column **preference, fruits**. For example the output dataframe I am looking for is:

```
name   preference   fruits
adam    likes       apples
adam    likes       orange
adam    dislikes    apple
adam    dislikes    orange
mike    likes       apples
mike    likes       orange
mike    dislikes    apple
mike    dislikes    orange
```

Wondering if it is possible. From my knowledge about pandas so far I believe I will have to use groupby?
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is it just cross product:

```
(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[col] for col in df],
                           names=df.columns)
   .to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
   name preference  fruits
0  adam      likes  apples
1  adam      likes  orange
2  adam   dislikes  apples
3  adam   dislikes  orange
4  mike      likes  apples
5  mike      likes  orange
6  mike   dislikes  apples
7  mike   dislikes  orange
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['adam', 'mike'],
    'preference': ['likes', 'dislikes'],
    'fruits': ['apples', 'oranges']
})

ndf = pd.DataFrame(
    product(*[df[c] for c in df.columns]),
    columns=df.columns
)

print(ndf)
#    name preference   fruits
# 0  adam      likes   apples
# 1  adam      likes  oranges
# 2  adam   dislikes   apples
# 3  adam   dislikes  oranges
# 4  mike      likes   apples
# 5  mike      likes  oranges
# 6  mike   dislikes   apples
# 7  mike   dislikes  oranges
```

As for speed, this seems to be a bit faster as well.

```
%%timeit
ndf = pd.DataFrame(
    product(*[df[c] for c in df.columns]),
    columns=df.columns
)
# 624 µs ± 32.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


%%timeit
(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[col] for col in df],
                           names=df.columns)
   .to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
)
# 3.51 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```